# "Permission dinied" for a simple app on Android 5.0

Tags: android, permission-denied, android-permissions

I have an app contains just one Activity and the next Manifest-file below. When I start it on an emulator (android 4.3) it works fine, Activity gets open, but I faced with error "Permission denied" trying to launch the app on my Nexus 5 with Android 5.0.
I'v also tried to build it with Sdk version 21, but it didn't help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="course.labs.dangerousapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <!--
          TODO - Using a permission element,
          define a custom permission with name
              "course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM" 
          and "dangerous" protection level.
    -->
    <permission
        android:name="course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM"
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous">
    </permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:permission = "course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM" >

        <!-- TODO - enforce the custom permission on this Activity -->

        <activity
            android:name=".DangerousActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <!--
                 TODO - add additional intent filter info so that this Activity
                  will respond to an Implicit Intent with the action
                  "course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY"
            -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `android:permission = "course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM"` from the `<application>` element.

First, this probably is supposed to go on an `<activity>`, given the permission name.

Second, the behavior of having `android:permission` on an `<application>` is generally undocumented. My guess is that it applies the permission to all components inside the application.

Third, nothing on the device, except perhaps another app that you wrote, will have a `<uses-permission>` element for this permission. Only such an app would be able to work with your app.

Comment: Thank you, but first, I tried to put android:permission = "course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM" to <activity>, it didn't help, it works fine with an amulator in both cases, but not with real device (Nexus 5), and second, yes I've got another app with <uses-permission> name = "course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM" and this app also can't work (start Activity) with the first app. But I want to say again I have no problem with these apps using an amulator. This makes me a bit crazy...

Comment: @ГлебКурганов: "it didn't help" -- you are preventing the home screen from launching your activity, because the home screen does not have the permission.

Comment: I was thinking about it too, but I'm newbie with Android and don't know how to give the permission to the home screen?

Comment: @ГлебКурганов: You cannot give the permission to the home screen, as you did not write the home screen. Hence, putting an `android:permission` attribute on your `LAUNCHER` activity is usually pointless.

Comment: Okay, I get it, but then how to explain that I can launch the app on an emulator?

Comment: @ГлебКурганов: Try tapping on the home screen launcher icon for your app. You should find that the activity does not launch. Running the activity from the IDE will work, as that uses low-level **`adb`** commands that apparently ignore permissions (which is a problem in its own right...).

Comment: Thank you a lot! You were right, now I completely get it. I just didn't know about ignoring permission by adb

Comment: @ГлебКурганов: It appears that the ability for **`adb`** to ignore the permission is perhaps limited to the emulator, which would explain why you are getting different behavior.